# ng2-pdf-viewer not working in production giving error

Tags: angular11, ng2-pdf-viewer

ng2-pdf-viewer working fine on lower environment but giving below error on production

> Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.11.338/legacy/build/pdf.worker.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' data: blob:

'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="src"></pdf-viewer>
```

src is a s3 presigned url

how to fix this?